# How to return a symbol to regular size after rotating

Tags: rotating

Using the packages graphicx, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, amsfonts, mathtools, tikz-cd, biblatex, comment, tikz.

I was trying to rotate the symbol $\Xi$, which I did with \def\Xic{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Xi$}}, but strangely it makes the symbol a bit smaller but I want it to maintain its original size, maybe even slightly larger.

Edit: It would also be nice if I could scale its height and width separately, because $\Xi$ does not occupy a perfect square.

Answer (score 1):

The first result looks a bit odd, I wonder who I can blame....

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\Xic{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Xi$}}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{$\Xi$}  \the\wd0, \the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0, \usebox{0}

\sbox2{\Xic}  \the\dimexpr\ht2+\dp2,  \the\wd2, \usebox{2}

hmmm,not what I expected, but:

\sbox4{\resizebox*{1em}{1em}{\usebox{0}}} \the\wd4, \the\dimexpr\ht4+\dp4, \usebox{4}

\sbox6{\resizebox*{1em}{1em}{\usebox{2}}} \the\wd6, \the\dimexpr\ht6+\dp6, \usebox{6}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it OK for me to be somewhat puzzled?

Comment: Is this the case: The above code measures the original character dimensions (bounding box), then after rotating 90 degrees, scales the rotated character so that its new vertical is equal to its former horizontal?

Comment: @rallg no,rotatebox does no scaling (and my code never has any bugs) so egreg's answer must be right and mine wrong as mine implies a bug, but I've been away from machine, just read the other answer, I'll need to think about it, I may delete this one

Answer (score 1):

It's by no means smaller, just an optical effect.

[image]

Now I rotate the PDF page

[image]

The source:

```
\documentclass[margin=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\fboxsep=0pt \fboxrule=0.1pt

\begin{document}

\fbox{$\Xi$} \fbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Xi$}}

\end{document}
```

Now what can we do? Remove the sidebearings, rotate, shift, adjust height and depth, add sidebearings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\Xic}{\mathord{% so it's only legal in math
  % we need to guess the sidebearings
  \sbox0{$\Xi$}%
  \kern0.06\wd0
  \scalebox{1.16}{\raisebox{-0.08\wd0}[0.88\wd0][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\copy0}}}%
  \kern0.06\wd0
}}

\fboxsep=0pt \fboxrule=0.1pt

\begin{document}

\fbox{$\Xi$} \fbox{$\Xic$}

$\Xi+\Xic$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sigh, this is the answer I hinted at in a (deleted) comment under the question but I got spooked by the box measuring in my answer and decided to eat dinner instead of worrying about it.  I'm still not sure if the box measuring I show in my answer is "expected" or something rotatebox should have adjusted for...